# Symfony 5 : send both sync and async mails in the app

Tags: php, symfony, mailer

I want to send emails in my symfony app both in sync and async mode. I followed the documentation of symfony messenger, but I have an issue with one key parameter : routing

```
framework:
   messenger:
      async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
      routing:
           'Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage':  async
```

With this configuration, all messages are sent in queue.

I have 2 services where I send emails sync in the first and async in the second :

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;

    class MailManagerAsync
    {
        protected $mailer;
    
        public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
        {
            $this->mailer = $mailer;
        }
    
        protected function sendMessage($subject, $body, $bodyText, $to, $context=[])
        {
            $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from($this->from)
                ->to(new Address($to))
                ->subject($subject)
    
                // path of the Twig template to render
                ->htmlTemplate($body)
                ->textTemplate($bodyText)
    
                // pass variables (name => value) to the template
                ->context($context)
            ;
    
            $this->mailer->send($email);
        }
    
        // function where i send emails
    
    }
```

The second is the same as this first, called MailManagerSync.

Now here is the problem :
when i change routing like this :

```
routing : 'App\Service\MailManagerAsync':  async
```

the app is sending 2 emails, 1 queued and one sent. I would like to send only one QUEUED.

Any suggestions ?

EDIT : I understand that I have to create a message class, and send it to the bus, but:
**is there any easy solution to have both sync and async emails without having to develop all I said above ?**

Comment: You are adding the service to the routing configuration. It doesn't work like that. You map the **message** class, not the service.

Comment: yes that is what i understood. But how do you pass a service as a message class ? (maybe extending some class ?)

Comment: No, you do not pass a service as a message object. the service should be just a message handler, the message just a data transport object.

Comment: Ok i see. But is there any easy solution to have both sync and async emails without having to develop a message class and so one ?

Comment: We discussed [this exact same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/70415915) a couple of days ago...

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a solution that could help other people. I think I did not come with it beacause this messenger thing is relatively new.

First create a message class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Message;

class EmailAsync
{
    private $subject;

    private $body;

    private $bodyText;

    private $recipient;

    private $context = [];

    public function __construct($subject, $body, $bodyText, $recipient, $context)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->bodyText = $bodyText;
        $this->recipient = $recipient;
        $this->context = $context;
    }
// setters and getter
```

This class will transport the email.
Then here is the handler :

```
<?php

namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Message\EmailAsync;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class EmailAsyncHandler  implements MessageHandlerInterface 
{

    protected $mailer;
    
    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function __invoke(EmailAsync $email)
    {
        $subject = $email->getSubject();
        $body = $email->getBody();
        $bodyText = $email->getBodyText();
        $recipient = $email->getRecipient();
        $context = $email->getContext();

        $emailToSend = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from("my-address@hello.com")
            ->to(new Address("your-address@hello.com"))
            ->subject($subject)

            // path of the Twig template to render
            ->htmlTemplate($body)
            ->textTemplate($bodyText)

            // pass variables (name => value) to the template
            ->context($context)
        ;

        $this->mailer->send($emailToSend);
    }
}
```

and now you can set the right routing parameter :

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            async: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

        routing:
            # Route your messages to the transports
            'App\Message\EmailAsync':  async
```

Now if i want to send an async mail, i use the bus within my service :

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Message\EmailAsync;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;

class MailManagerAsync
{
    protected $bus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $bus)
    {
        $this->bus = $bus;
    }

    protected function sendMessage($subject, $body, $bodyText, $to, $context = [])
    {
        $emailAsync = new EmailAsync($subject, $body, $bodyText, $to, $context);
        $this->bus->dispatch($emailAsync);
    }

// SEND EMAILS

}
```